# Error with node_modules after I decreased the node_modules

Tags: javascript, angular, node-modules

So I have some node_modules with a total amount of 800 mb

So I did this:

```
npm install -production
```

And now the npm_modules have the size of: 344 mb.

But if I try to run angular with npm start. I get this error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from "C:\\source\\nien\\cityflows\\src\\dashboard-frontend".
See "C:\Users\nien\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-M2OCCf\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

But if I install this module: @angular-devkit/build-angular

Then my npm_moduels are again 800 MB.

So what I have to do now?

Thank you.

Oke, here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "dashboard-frontend",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve -o",
    "build": "ng build --stats.json --prod=true --deleteOutputPath=false",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "npm run lint.eslint && npm run lint.prettier && npm run lint.types",
    "lint.eslint": "eslint . --ext ts",
    "lint.prettier": "prettier -c src/**/*.ts",
    "lint.types": "tsc --noEmit",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "browser": {
    "fs": false,
    "path": false,
    "os": false
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-material-components/datetime-picker": "^5.0.3",
    "@angular/animations": "~10.2.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "10.2.7",
    "@angular/common": "~10.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.2.1",
    "@angular/core": "~10.2.1",
    "@angular/elements": "10.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.2.1",
    "@angular/material": "10.2.7",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^11.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.2.1",
    "@angular/router": "~10.2.1",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "0.7.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "1.2.30",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "5.14.0",
    "@mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder": "4.7.0",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.15",
    "@types/mocha": "^8.0.4",
    "angular-auth-oidc-client": "^11.2.0",
    "angular-gridster2": "10.1.6",
    "angular-plotly.js": "3.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "4.5.2",
    "bootstrap-icons": "1.3.0",
    "idb": "6.0.0",
    "jasmine": "^3.6.3",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "luxon": "1.25.0",
    "mapbox-gl": "^1.12.0",
    "material-icons": "^0.3.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "ngx-mapbox-gl": "4.8.1",
    "plotly.js": "1.55.2",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "ts-jest": "^26.4.4",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1102.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.2.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "~10.2.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.5.14",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/luxon": "1.25.0",
    "@types/mapbox-gl": "1.12.5",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.62",
    "@types/plotly.js": "^1.50.21",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.4.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.4.1",
    "eslint": "^7.11.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.13.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.4",
    "gzipper": "^4.4.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "prettier": "^2.1.2",
    "prettier-eslint": "^11.0.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.5"
  }
}
```

And here is my angular.json file:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "dashboard-frontend": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/dashboard-frontend",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"


            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.css",
              "./node_modules/mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css",
              "./node_modules/@mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder/lib/mapbox-gl-geocoder.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/plotly.js/dist/plotly.min.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [{
                "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
              }],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [{
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "4mb",
                  "maximumError": "6mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "dashboard-frontend:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "dashboard-frontend:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "dashboard-frontend:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "codeCoverage": true,
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "dashboard-frontend:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "dashboard-frontend:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "dashboard-frontend",
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false
  }
}
```

Oke, I have it now like this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1102.1",
    "@angular-material-components/datetime-picker": "^5.0.3",
    "@angular/animations": "~10.2.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "10.2.7",
    "@angular/common": "~10.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.2.1",
    "@angular/core": "~10.2.1",
    "@angular/elements": "10.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.2.1",
    "@angular/material": "10.2.7",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^11.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.2.1",
    "@angular/router": "~10.2.1",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "0.7.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "1.2.30",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "5.14.0",
    "@mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder": "4.7.0",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.15",
    "@types/mocha": "^8.0.4",
    "angular-auth-oidc-client": "^11.2.0",
    "angular-gridster2": "10.1.6",
    "angular-plotly.js": "3.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "4.5.2",
    "bootstrap-icons": "1.3.0",
    "idb": "6.0.0",
    "jasmine": "^3.6.3",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "luxon": "1.25.0",
    "mapbox-gl": "^1.12.0",
    "material-icons": "^0.3.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "ngx-mapbox-gl": "4.8.1",
    "plotly.js": "1.55.2",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "ts-jest": "^26.4.4",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.2.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "~10.2.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.5.14",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/luxon": "1.25.0",
    "@types/mapbox-gl": "1.12.5",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.62",
    "@types/plotly.js": "^1.50.21",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.4.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.4.1",
    "eslint": "^7.11.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.13.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.4",
    "gzipper": "^4.4.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "prettier": "^2.1.2",
    "prettier-eslint": "^11.0.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.5"
  }
```

And So I did a npm install -production. But my node_modules are now: 591 MB big.

And if I do a npm start:

I get this errors:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module 'typescript'
Require stack:
- C:\source\nien\cityflows\src\dashboard-frontend\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\dev-server\index.js
- C:\Users\nien\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js
- C:\Users\nien\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\index.js
- C:\Users\nien\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js
- C:\Users\nien\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\serve-impl.js
- C:\Users\nien\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\export-ref.js
- C:\Users\nien\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\index.js
- C:\Users\nien\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\utilities\json-schema.js
- C:\Users\nien\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js
- C:\Users\nien\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\cli\index.js
- C:\Users\nien\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\init.js
- C:\Users\nien\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng
See "C:\Users\nien\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-0FRknQ\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

Oke I also upgraded to angualr 11. But I get this info:

```
√ Browser application bundle generation complete.
√ ES5 bundle generation complete.

Initial Chunk Files                      | Names                |      Size
scripts.3cf268d47c462590e7d9.js          | scripts              |   3.27 MB
main-es5.87f2f0f48772e84377c6.js         | main                 |   2.49 MB
main-es2015.87f2f0f48772e84377c6.js      | main                 |   2.36 MB
styles.d540d930321db4c962dc.css          | styles               | 245.64 kB
polyfills-es5.259ae27e17f48bc03647.js    | polyfills-es5        | 131.80 kB
polyfills-es2015.732b81c0b5a3e3dbb1bc.js | polyfills            |  36.16 kB
runtime-es2015.a4dadbc03350107420a4.js   | runtime              |   1.45 kB
runtime-es5.a4dadbc03350107420a4.js      | runtime              |   1.45 kB

                                         | Initial ES5 Total    |   6.13 MB
                                         | Initial ES2015 Total |   5.91 MB
```

But I still get this error:

```
Error: bundle initial-es5 exceeded maximum budget. Budget 6.00 MB was not met by 133.51 kB with a total of 6.13 MB.
```

when I do a `ng build --prod.`

Comment: Can you post your package.json, your angular-devkit might be mentioned in devDependencies

Comment: Move @angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1102.1", from devDependencies to dependencies

Comment: install typescript globally "npm install -g typescript"

Answer (score 1):

`@angular-devkit/build-angular` is to build an Angular application.

`npm install -production` will install only `dependencies` from `package.json`.

Use `npm build --prod` after `npm install -production` to create a **prod build** and use any Web Server to host.

For typescript error in logs, try to install typescript globally `npm install -g typescript`

Comment: Oke, But have I to remove first all node_modules and then do a npm install --production? Because i do that. and then I do a ng build --prod but then I get this errors: An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module 'typescript'
Require stack:
- C:\source\nien\cityflows\src\dashboard-frontend\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\browser\index.js

Comment: "npm build --prod", you will get production build in dist folder, you need all node_modules to run project locally.